# Saving data through JPA sometime causes strange error: java.lang.String cannot be cast to enum

Tags: java, jpa, enums

I'm trying to save some data into the database through JPA.
Here's my entity and my enum:

```
public enum MyEnum implements java.io.Serializable {
    MyValue,
    MyOtherValue
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "myenum")
    private MyEnum myenum;

    public MyEnum getMyEnum() { return myenum; }
    public void setMyEnum(MyEnum parameter) { this.myenum = parameter; }
}
```

And I try to save my entity by calling the EntityManager's merge method.

What I get back is: "java.lang.String cannot be cast to MyEnum".
The strange part is that the possibility of this scenario is 80% on our production environment, and 20% on our test environment.

I tried to debug the code to see what happens inside, but I reached this error only once. Then I restarted our webserver (WildFly) and I can't reproduce.

So what could be the problem?

**Update**: if I restart WildFly, the problem not comes out for a while... but after an unknown time or I don't know what, I can't save my entity again because of this casting error.

Comment: Any your database did not already contain invalid values (not MyValue and not MyOtherValue)?

Comment: hi maestro, what is the database used? what is the database column type used for the field, `MyEnum`?

Comment: Changed the title of your questions; as some folks will only read the title and think "some newbie asking a stupid question" and worst case downvote you without no good reason.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @home: no I checked my values and its consistent with my model.

Comment: @Saravana Kumar: we use Oracle with Hibernate 10g dialect, the type of the column is varchar2(255 char).

Comment: @mp911de: I can't post the stacktrace because on production because of some mystical reasons we catch it and just log a user friendly message and on test environment I'm still unable to reproduce but I working on it

Comment: I'd check the values of this database; is there perhaps a particular value in there that is not actually an existing enum value in MyEnum? I'd make that check very thorough, up to checking for added spaces

Comment: @Gimby: I checked the values multiple times but there's no inconsistency in DB (no added spaces or any whitespace or mistyping or anything else...)